# thread communication vs process communication

Tags: multithreading, process, communication

Can anyone explain the difference between thread communication and process communication and give few examples of each type of communication?

Comment: dear Arjun, no this is not a homework question. Yes I've searched my "favorite" search engine. After searching I haven't found any answer that satisfied me. Next time if you don't have anything smart to answer, please try to curve your enthusiasm and don't answer anything at all.

Comment: @OP: I'm Sorry that you chose to take offense and be rude. Your question showed (and still shows) nothing about what you tried and which part you didn't get/understand. Usually, on SO, people expect the OP to have put in some effort before asking a question. If you read your question again, you might notice that yours doesn't cut it. I was just trying to help by pointing this out *so you can improve your question* (and that at least 3 people agree with me).

Comment: on SO it is best to try to ask the questions as simple as possible and not try to complicate the question so it would be easier for other people to answer. I could start elaborating that I've searched all over the net and tell what I've learned but why complicate? You wanted me to say in the question where I've searched and the amount of time it took me so you would be convinced that I didn't came to OS right on the start? Your response was offensive and arrogant. I've asked the question in the most simple manner that I know.

Comment: I just wanted to know the exact difference between the two. Also I believe that an answer to this sort of question would help later on for other people that will want to know the difference and it all would be written in one place instead of being scattered all over the net without getting the exact answer.

Comment: OK. Good luck. Hope you get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Arjun has a problem with your question - look at it - does it look like a computer science homework/coursework/exam question to you?  It did to Arjun, and it does to me, even though it may not be.  It's quite a broad question and it IS fairly easy to find satisfactory information on Google - I tried it.  To put it another way, it is offensive and arrogant to con experienced developers into wasting their time doing complete homework assignments for students that can not be bothered to work themselves.  This happens a lot here, so try to understand Arjun's reluctance to answer your question.

Comment: I understand, but Arjun could choose like 99.99999999% of users in SO to just not answer the question instead of responding as he did. Its OK to choose not to answer the question of course, but he chose in my opinion, to reply an offensive response and that's that bothered me. That's why I said that if you don't have something useful to say and help then it's better not to say anything at all.

Comment: I could also have chosen to downvote your question and not explain why. Currently, you have 4 downvotes and the your only response is to rage on the guy who pointed out why you got them. I hope you don't get offended again from this. Anyway, I see that you have a 'satisfactory' answer. Thats good.

Comment: @Arjun He's asking a perfectly valid question. Perhaps its beneath your pay grade, but if you don't like the question, just ignore it. I'm sure we don't _all_ have the extensive experience you have. That is all.

Comment: @user48956 the strategy you suggest (ignoring questions) is certainly a reasonable one. Don't you think mine is too? I wasn't hurling insults at the OP or anything. If you read all my comments, you might see that my initial comment was only trying to help produce *what I thought* was a better question from the OP. The OP vigorously disagreed with me, which might be a reasonable response as well. Anyway, the question has actually been answered to the OP's satisfaction more than 2 years ago, so this discussion is moot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thread communication can be as simple as sharing a variable or object bearing in mind that synchronization is required. Interprocess communication is a bit harder and much slower since processes are separated and cannot intervene. For this type of communication you can use named pipes, memory mapped files, msmq, TCP, WCF, file system and other.

Answer (score 4):

Threads share same memory. so communication is much faster when compared to the process communication. process use shared memory, pipe and message queuing for the communications.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one heap within one process and all threads in a process shares that heap. so when communicating within threads of a process, synchronisation is the key. The ways, one can communicate with in threads are:

- Shared memory : Create shared memory buffer pools and you can use Unix Domain Sockets to send instant messages/notifications on when to read/write data.(Just one use case)
- Conditional variables with mutexes (I like this approach as c++
  programmer)

However, since processes have their own boundaries, the way of communications usually are:

- Socket,File, pipes and message queues.
- Shared memory: This is different as this memory is not allocated
  within a process boundary,     unlike in case of threads.